# How to find which control is currently selected by the user on the page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to find that which control is been selected by the user, Is there any way to find which controls is currently selected by user in windows store app using c#.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the GotFocus event for every control that you want and then you can assign that to a variable.

```
private void UserControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    controlFocused = e.OriginalSource as Control;
}
```